# HTML Layout Error

Tags: html, layout

I created a Website and a new Privacy Policy for the EU-Privacy Update.
When the webpage is zoomed out, the link for Privacy works perfectly fine, but when zooming in you can not click it anymore. 
I searched on the internet but did not find any solution to the problem.

www.arianeschaefer.16mb.com

Comment: I guess the website performance it the real issue in this case, not the zooming.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212).

Comment: I agree with Viachelsav. The site design seems messy. Still I have given you a workaround that will make it work for you

Comment: I am pretty new with HTML Coding. Is that the Templates fault or my fault with editing.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` on .side_menu_section div

```
.menu_block .side_menu_section {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer so that other users can know that this solution worked for you and it can be helpful to them if they ever have similar issues